# Do you get money back from the IRS if you have no income for 2021 and its your first time filing taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

My cousin never filed a tax return before in his life as he never made any income. Should he file a tax return to claim any free IRS money for those with no income? He did get the free government stimulus money the prior years. This is for New York. And how much money would he get if he filed.

Comment: Does he have children? To my knowledge all refundable credits are based on having dependent (e.g. child tax credit). There's no "free money" simply from having no income.

Comment: There is a Covid check of 1400$ for every citizen. If he didn’t get it yet, he will get it when he files!

Comment: Did he get all three Economic Impact Payments ($1200, $600, and $1400)?

Answer (score 1):

The IRS is not a charity and doesn't give money out to anyone just because they ask for it.

There are however cases where you can get a *refundable credit* even if you owe no taxes or had no income. The COVID-19 stimulus checks are example of such credit. In some cases a return has to be filed for these checks to be sent to you even if you had no income or are not otherwise required to file a return.

Going through the income tax preparation software questionnaire or talking to a tax prepare may uncover additional potential credits that your cousin may be entitled to.